# How to see/list history of all wiki contributions/edits by an author/user in wiki.ubuntu.com (MoinMoin?)

Tags: launchpad, ubuntu-wiki

I have logged in some time ago in wiki.ubuntu.com, making some edits. Now I have logged in again (always via my Launchpad ID) - and when I click on my username, all I get is some preferences, as described in [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HelpOnUserPreferences).

If you click on Info on the [main page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Home?action=info),  (I guess that is like "View History" in MediaWiki); you can see that the users are linked either via their Launchpad homepage (which I actually expected), or by their email. But then - you cannot call up a history list of Ubuntu Wiki edits on the Launchpad page!?

In MediaWiki, one can simply append `wiki/Special:Contributions/username` to the wiki URL, and get all user's contributions... So how on earth could I find the same information for myself in the Ubuntu Wiki?

Answer (score 1):

Ah well - here's my progress:

```
$ hg clone http://hg.moinmo.in/moin/2.0 moin-2.0-hg
requesting all changes
...
683 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

$ grep -ri contributions moin-2.0-hg/
moin-2.0-hg/MoinMoin/apps/frontend/views.py:    :returns: the list of all items with user userid's contributions
moin-2.0-hg/README.txt:contributions - please see the MoinMoinAcknowledgements page there:
...

$ grep -ri contributions -B6 moin-2.0-hg/MoinMoin/apps/frontend/views.py
def _mychanges(userid):
    """
    Returns a list with all names of items which user userid has contributed to.

    :param userid: user itemid
    :type userid: unicode
    :returns: the list of all items with user userid's contributions

$ grep -ri mychanges moin-2.0-hg/
moin-2.0-hg/MoinMoin/apps/admin/templates/user/index_user.html:    <li><a href="{{ url_for('frontend.mychanges') }}">{{ _("My Changes") }}</a></li>
moin-2.0-hg/MoinMoin/apps/frontend/_tests/test_frontend.py:    def test_mychanges(self):
moin-2.0-hg/MoinMoin/apps/frontend/_tests/test_frontend.py:        self._test_view('frontend.mychanges', viewopts=dict(userid='000000'))
moin-2.0-hg/MoinMoin/apps/frontend/views.py:@frontend.route('/+mychanges')
moin-2.0-hg/MoinMoin/apps/frontend/views.py:def mychanges():
moin-2.0-hg/MoinMoin/apps/frontend/views.py:    my_changes = _mychanges(flaskg.user.itemid)
moin-2.0-hg/MoinMoin/apps/frontend/views.py:def _mychanges(userid):
moin-2.0-hg/docs/user/accounts.rst: **MOINTODO** +mychanges only links to the item which you edit, not the specific revision. If you edit
moin-2.0-hg/docs/user/accounts.rst: **MOINTODO** +mychanges isn't very pretty if you visit it without making any changes, it just says
```

So looking up `+mychanges`, I found [thomaswaldmann / moin-2.0 / issues / #150 - /+mychanges links to items rather than specific revisions — Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/thomaswaldmann/moin-2.0/issue/150/mychanges-links-to-items-rather-than):

> `http://127.0.0.1:8080/+mychanges/` currently shows a list of items which the logged in user has modified (with one link to the item per edit, each on separate lines).

Right, so I give that a try on the Ubuntu wiki, while I'm logged in:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/+mychanges/

... but no, the wiki responds: "This page does not exist yet. You can create a new empty page, or use one of the page templates." ... so I guess the Ubuntu wiki MoinMoin is older version than the latest, which apparently does feature user contribution log. Darn...

Comment: It's better add additional stuff in the question proper rather than as an answer unless, of course, you are actually posting an answer to your own question.